# Zend framework with default and mobile layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, wurfl

currently i have a zend framework application, i integrate it with wurfl user agent, so i can switch between mobile and desktop version, my plugin reside in library

```
<?php
 class Zc_Controller_Plugin_TemplatePicker extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
  {
protected $useragent;


public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
    $this->useragent = $bootstrap->getResource('useragent');

    if($this->useragent->getDevice()->getType() == 'mobile')
    {
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('mobile');
    }

}
 }
```

and now i have 2 layouts in script file mobile.phtml and layout.phtml, hw can i use some of the controller function so that it can be use for mobile layout, also i have layout loader in bootstrap

```
    protected function _initLayoutHelper()
{
   // $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
   // $front->registerPlugin(new Zc_Controller_Plugin_TemplatePicker());  
    if(!stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/admin')){
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    }
    $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Zc_Controller_Action_Helper_LayoutLoader());
}
```

and the layoutloader code is

```
<?php

class Zc_Controller_Action_Helper_LayoutLoader extends   
  Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
 {
public function preDispatch(){

    $bootstrap = $this->getActionController()->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    $config = $bootstrap->getOptions();
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
    $controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();

    $layoutScript = "layout";
    if (isset($config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'])) {
        $layoutScript = $config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'];
    }
    $this->getActionController()->getHelper('layout')->setLayout($layoutScript);
}
 }
```

where should i tweak now so that i can have 1 controller class with 2 separate layout.Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you want 1 controller with 2 separate layouts, then modify `mobile.phtml` and `layout.phtml` so that they are different... Visit your site with a PC to see layout #2, and with your mobile to see #1. That should be everything you need, provided the user-agent-sniffing plugin works ok.

Comment: that things is work..i can get view of both different layout from different device, what my ques is using the controller that already defined for default controller for mobile template.

Comment: Still I have no idea what your question really is, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to set some certain layout for the certain controller, you can use the following code:

```
class Custom_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();

        switch ($front->getRequest()->getControllerName()) {
            case "index":
                $layout->setLayout('home');
                break;
            case "login":
                $layout->setLayout('login');
                break;
            default:
                $layout->setLayout('default');
        }
    }

}
```